# Autocomplete in search bar : different users with same username

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, autocomplete

I am creating a social media platform and came across this issue which I couldn't fix. I have a database table USERS which have usernames and email (email is different for everyone). However, users can have same username.
When I'm searching a user through autocomplete in the search bar, it is showing all usernames with that particular starting string which I've searched.
Now i want that when I click on a particular username, his profile should open. but there are people with same username. how would I do so.

some points to be noted :

- I'm creating an array of usernames and passing that array to js for autocomplete to use.
- An auto incremented ID is attached with each user

below is the script for autocomplete :

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  
  var currentFocus;
  
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
     
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
     
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
         
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
         
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
             
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
       
        currentFocus++;
        
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        
        currentFocus--;
        
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
         
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {   
    if (!x) return false;    
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {   
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  } 
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
      });
}

var user_names = <?php echo json_encode($names) ;?>
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), user_names);
```

- user_names : it is the array of user names I obtained from the PHP file

Comment: You have id from user table , so go link like `domain/user/{id}` when clicked

Comment: Why do you allow users with the same name? How is anyone supposed to know which is which?

Comment: Similar to facebook. emails are different but names can be same

Comment: @DavidJorHpan user names can be same, so it will basically open all users with that name.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma Along with usernames, show their email ids next to their names in auto-complete dropdown box. So based on the name and email, you can filter users

Comment: What I'm doing currently is I extracted all unique names from the username array, so that autocomplete would only show unique names. when clicked, user will be directed to a page containing profile cards of all people with that name along with their profile pics. user now can click on the required profile and view.